# Menu Item disappears in VS2008 when I add a width, but appears when I build

Tags: wpf, xaml, menu, menuitem

I'm very confused about this - as I mentioned in the title everything is okay when I build, but when I'm developing the code the fact that what is appearing in Visual Studio is different to what I get when I build is unsettling. Maybe someone can see what is going on?

Basically, I am unable to define widths for menu items or the header text disappears. It works fine when building though. I've included some screenshots and my code to make this easier to understand.

Thanks

With no width defined, the alignment is strange:

[image: strange alignment]

If I define a width, the text disappears!

[image: text disappears!]

Yet if I do define a width, while the text doesn't appear in Visual Studio when I run the application it does perfectly!

[image: works perfectly]

If anyone has any ideas that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I propose to do not change a Width of main menu items. It looks...  non-standard.

Comment: well your links dont work anymore ... but have you tried a stackpanel for example or a grid? i had a similiar problem when i started with WPF and was using the default view